# Convert a 2D array to a string

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I would like to convert each element of a 2D array to a string, within an `each` **But I cannot use `do`** (specific requirement - this is homework). The array is called `families`, and is defined as follows:

```
#family.rb

class FamilyDetails

  attr_accessor :name, :sex, :status, :age
  def initialize (name, sex, type, role, age)
    @name = name
    @sex = sex
    @type = type
    @role = role
    @age = age
  end

end

# Below, an array is created called families; instances of the class are then instantiated within the array elements
families = []

families << FamilyDetails.new('Andrew','Male', 'Child', 'Son' , '27' )
families << FamilyDetails.new('Bill','Male', 'Parent', 'Father' , '63' )
families << FamilyDetails.new('Samantha','Female', 'Parent', 'Mother' , '62' )
families << FamilyDetails.new('Thomas','Male', 'Child', 'Dog' , '10' )
families << FamilyDetails.new('Samantha', 'Female', 'Child', 'Dog' , '4' )
```

I have attempted to use the `join` method as follows:

```
def arrayeachsearch(an_array)
  an_array.each
    output = an_array.join(" ")
  puts output
end

arrayeachsearch(families)
```

However this results in the following output:

```
#<FamilyDetails:0x00000002358110> #<FamilyDetails:0x000000027c7f48> #<FamilyDetails:0x000000027c7e58> #<FamilyDetails:0x000000027c7d68> #<FamilyDetails:0x000000027c7c78>
```

I am hoping for output like this (I have surrounded `information from the array like this`):

- Family member 1 is `Andrew` who is `Male`, a `Child`; specifically, a
  `Son` aged `27`
- Family member 2 is `Bill` who is `Male`, a `Parent`;
  specifically, a `Father` aged `63`
- Family member 3 is `Samantha` who
  is `Male`, a `Parent`; specifically, a `Mother` aged `62`
- Family
  member 4 is `Thomas` who is `Male`, a `Child`; specifically, a `Dog`
  aged `10`
- Family member 5 is `Samantha` who is `Female`, a `Child`;
  specifically, a `Dog` aged `4`

What is the best way to go about this? Forgive my lack of knowledge, and thanks for any help - appreciated.

Comment: is this homework or what?

Comment: Who says you can't use `do`? A customer who has no clue how to program? Why do you have to use `each`? This smells like homework which should be disclosed if so.

Comment: Yes it is homework - I did not know this had to be disclosed (edited to disclose this fact!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `:role` and `:type` to `attr_accessor` you can use:

```
families.each.with_index(1) { |member, index|
  puts "Family member #{index} is #{member.name} who is #{member.sex}, a #{member.type}; specifically, a #{member.role} aged #{member.age}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class FamilyDetails

  attr_accessor :name, :sex, :status, :age
  def initialize (i, name, sex, type, role, age)
    @i = i
    @name = name
    @sex = sex
    @type = type
    @role = role
    @age = age
  end

  def to_s
    "Family member #{@i} is #{name} who is #{sex}, a #{type}; specifically, a #{role} aged #{age}"
  end
end
```

Then you can simply do

```
puts families
```

Comment: Thanks - this works - except for the `#{@i}` bit (Had to accept Stefan as his was the first answer)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me you have a one dimensional array, you can probably do something like

```
counter = 0
for member in families
  counter += 1
  puts "Family member %i is %s who is %s, a %s, a %s, age %i." %[counter, member.name, member.sex, member.type, member.role, member.age]
end
```

Comment: there is no method `++` in ruby

Comment: i guess your answer is in python??

Comment: it was more Ruby inspired pseudo!

Comment: Thanks - this works (Had to accept Stefan as his was the first answer)